# PHP: reading a text file and executing SQL statements to MySQL

Tags: php, file-io

I want to create a form in PHP that will load a .sql file, read its contents, and execute those statements against a MySQL database.

Currently using function `get_file_contents` but it's not working. What can I do?

Comment: Please post some code. It's impossible to give an answer without more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you have several queries in your file, you'll either have to :

- split the file into multiple distinct queries, and use either [`mysql_query`](http://fr.php.net/mysql_query) or [`mysqli_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for each one of those queries.

  - those two functions cannot execute more than one query per call : quoting the [manual page of `mysql_query`](https://www.php.net/mysql_query) : "*multiple queries are not supported*"
- use [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) to send several queries at once

  - There is no equivalent using the [`mysql_*`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) family of functions
- use the `mysql` command-line client, to import the file, with something like this *(you'll have to pass the right values, of course)* :

  - `mysql --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --host=localhost DATABASENAME < your-file.sql`

Answer (score 0):

I use this bit of Java code to import sql queries, it basically splits the file into lines using a specific regexp, and strip comment prefixes created by mysqldump.
porting this to PHP should be pretty straight forward.

```
public static void importSQL(Connection conn, InputStream in) throws SQLException
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
    s.useDelimiter("(;\\s*(\r)?\n)|(--\n)");
    Statement st = null;
    int lineNum = 0;
    try
    {
        st = conn.createStatement();
        while (s.hasNext())
        {
            String line = s.next();
            if (line.startsWith("/*!") && line.endsWith("*/"))
            {
                int i = line.indexOf(' ');
                line = line.substring(i + 1, line.length() - " */".length());
            }

            if (line.trim().length() > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    st.execute(line);
                }
                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    logger.error("Error executing line #" + lineNum +  " : " + line , e);
                    throw e;
                }
            }

            lineNum++;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (st != null) st.close();
    }
}
```

an alternative is to call mysql command line via system.
something like :

```
<?php
system("mysql -u $user -p$password $dbname < $filename");
?>
```

but is not a very good idea for production code for various reasons (performance, security implications you should be aware of etc).